# Arduino digital output pin controling relay problem

Tags: arduino-mega, relay

I try my code to change the state of a relay on pushing a push button buy checking the state of a digital pin.

**My code :**

```
const int led1 = 6;
const int enable1 = 7;
boolean led1_OnOff;
long now;
int minSecsBetweenUpdates = 1; // 1 seconds
long lastSend = -minSecsBetweenUpdates * 1000l;

void setup() {
  led1_OnOff = false;
  pinMode(enable1, INPUT);
  pinMode(led1, OUTPUT);
}

void loop() {
  now = millis();
  if (now > (lastSend + minSecsBetweenUpdates * 1000l))
  {
    if(digitalRead(enable1) == HIGH)
    {
      lastSend = now;
      if(led1_OnOff == true)
      {
        led1_OnOff = false;
        //+digitalWrite(led1, LOW);
      }
      else
      {
        led1_OnOff = true;
        //digitalWrite(led1, HIGH);
      }
    }
  }

  if(led1_OnOff == true)
    digitalWrite(led1, HIGH);
  else
    digitalWrite(led1, LOW);
}
```

But the code keeps on looping and the relay keep changing it's state as if pin 7 is always high, I'm sure of my schematic but I don't know what's wrong with my code.

**for those who want my schematic:**

[image]

Comment: Did you wired pin 7? If it was floating, it will read as HIGH (mostly) and LOW sometimes. BTW your interval checking is incorrect, it doesn't work when value is expected to overflow (somewhere at 49th day). Checking the elapsed time (subtracted difference) with period value will work OK.

Comment: Perhaps you should post your wiring diagram for bigger chance to get a proper answer

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error while trying to drive relay through the state of a digital input pin in Arduino](http://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/34032/error-while-trying-to-drive-relay-through-the-state-of-a-digital-input-pin-in-ar)

Comment: Did the code I gave you for your practically identical question yesterday help?

Comment: no it didn't, my code was working but suddenly it has gone crazy, I even tried your code but it keeps on looping like enable1 is always high

Comment: What makes you sure your wiring is correct?

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that you are basically saying "while the pin is HIGH toggle the relay" rather than "When, and only when, the pin *transitions from LOW to HIGH* do I toggle the relay".

To do that you must remember what state the pin was in during the last iteration:

```
const uint8_t led1 = 6;
const uint8_t enable1 = 7;

void setup() {
    pinMode(enable1, INPUT);
    pinMode(led1, OUTPUT);
}

void loop() {
    static bool led1_OnOff = false;
    static bool lastValue = digitalRead(enable1);

    bool currentValue = digitalRead(enable1);

    if (currentValue != lastValue) {
        lastValue = currentValue;
        if (currentValue == HIGH) {
            led1_OnOff = !led1_OnOff;
            digitalWrite(led1, led1_OnOff);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried that but I have the same problem, always keeps looping like crazy and only stops looping when I hit the push button

Comment: How have you wired up the pushbutton?

Comment: It's not a small push button for arduino, it's a normal lighting AC push button, I user one side for pin 7 and the other for 5V

Comment: So no pulldown resistor? No wonder it's spazzing out - the pin is floating until you press the button and connect it to a signal of some form. Read the basic Arduino button tutorial: https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/Button

Comment: that was the problem, thanks for pointing it out...I didn't know I had to use a resistor for the AC standard push button like the arduino small push button.

Comment: A button is just a button - two metal contacts that get pressed together. Regardless of if it's for AC, DC, high voltage, low voltage, momentary, toggle, rocker, whatever. That is all they are - just two metal contacts that press together.

Comment: It now works but if I keep pushing the push button it keeps changing the relay state every one second (my pre-defined time interval), I want it to keep it's state if I keep pushing the push button and only change it if I take my hands of it and pushed it again, can you help?

Comment: Which code are you using - your original code, or my code I posted above?

Comment: my original code, I tried yours but it's not working, the delay that I add keeps it steadier but if I keep pushing the pushing button it keeps looping and changing the state of the relay every second

Comment: In what way does my code not work?

Comment: please check this [link](http://arduino.stackexchange.com/a/34041/17349)

Answer (score 1):

You say your switch is between pin 7 and +5v.  Therefore you will need a pull-down resistor on pin 7.

You say that setting pin 7 to an output works.  However you are very likely to burn out the output like this.  A pull-down resistor is the way to go.

Comment: no it's connected to 5V and pin 7...I think I solved it by setting enable1 pin to OUTPUT in the setup() loop and forcing it to start at low state by calling digitalWrite(enable1, LOW);

Comment: In that case, you will need a pull DOWN resistor.

Comment: no that's only what I did, when I set enable1 to output it goes crazy but when I set it to input it's fine.

Comment: `void setup() {
  led1_OnOff = false;

  pinMode(enable1, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(enable1, LOW);
  pinMode(led1, OUTPUT);
}

void loop() {
  now = millis();
  if (now > (lastSend + 1000))
  {
    if(digitalRead(enable1) == HIGH)
    {
      lastSend = now;
      if(led1_OnOff == true)
        led1_OnOff = false;
      else
        led1_OnOff = true;
    }
  }

  if(led1_OnOff == true)
    digitalWrite(led1, HIGH);
  else
      digitalWrite(led1, LOW);
}`

Comment: OK, I understand what's happening now. Answer updated. You'll blow up your Arduino if you do it like that.

Comment: It now works but if I keep pushing the push button it keeps changing the relay state every one second (my pre-defined time interval), I want it to keep it's state if I keep pushing the push button and only change it if I take my hands of it and pushed it again, can you help?

Comment: Are you using either my, or @Majenko's, method for detecting when you release the button?

Comment: I used both but they both don't work so I'm using mine which is steadier if I push the push button and let go, but if I keep pushing it keeps looping.

Comment: Then I think you have another, as yet undiscovered, problem. Both methods should work.

Comment: I haven't added anything else except that I added a pull down transistor between pin 7 and ground.

Comment: My point stands.  Your solution may be sufficient for you, which is fine, but there is an undiscovered problem, otherwise it would work perfectly.  Perhaps it's interference on that cable - you could try moving the switch right next to the Arduino.

Comment: please check this [link](http://arduino.stackexchange.com/a/34041/17349)

Comment: What you have there is a cludge to avoid addressing the real problem. If you're happy with that, OK, but know that's what it is.  Also, if you want to encourage people to help you further, consider at least up-voting, or better accepting, helpful answers.

Comment: I did up-vote your answer but they said it will be considered as I don't have enough reputation to up-vote you directly...beside, what is wrong with my code?, it's the one that I tried actually and did work for me, It's not a competition here, and I didn't ask this question to have more reputation, I did ask this question to have help and you did help but your code doesn't work for me, that doesn't mean that I'm better, it just means that I found a code that is more suitable for me...thanks for your help and thanks for your understanding.